Is it possible to sort a list in Freemarker on two columns?
We have a list of "items" coming into a Freemarker PDF template. That list has multiple values for each "item". That list is sorted by a default value, but we want to sort by "item group" first and then within those groups, by "item name".
This is what that data looks like:

ID 123

Item group:  Group A
Item name: ABC
...


ID 124

Item group:  Group D
Item name: DEF
...


ID 125

Item group:  Group A
Item name: RST
...



Right now, we have this in the Freemarker:
<#list record.item?sort_by("item") as item> 
   ...(table details here) 
</#list>

That works just fine to sort the list on item name only.
I want the list to be generated in this order though in a table:



Group
Item




Group A
ABC


Group A
RST


Group D
DEF



Thanks for any tips!

I have not used freemarker, but an easily overlooked example within a template in their docs for sort_by, you might be able to do: sort_by(["group", "item"])?

@PaulT. nope https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_sort_by

@JasperdeVries ok, but the second template example at that link shows such usage? ... which is why I mentioned easily overlooked.

No, it's about sorting on a property of child objects in the sequence, not about sorting on multiple properties.

Right, @JasperdeVries, PaulT. 's idea doesn't solve this, as the "group" is not a sub-level piece of data, relative to the "name".

I ended up solving this myself by adding the combined Group + item name into the source data coming into the Freemarker template, and then just using this to sort the list on that value:
<#list record.item?sort_by("combined_name_and_group") as item> 

This is resolved for me.

If you have modified the Java class in the data-model just for this anyway, then maybe it's nicer to add record.item.sorted() or sortedByGroupAndName(). Another possibility is to add some companion object like ReportUtils.sortItems(record.item). And then of course there's my answer of how to do it purely with template language features, however, the template wasn't originally meant to do this level of data processing.

?sort_by does stable sorting (which needs to be documented), therefore you can do this: records?sort_by("item")?sort_by("group"). I deliberately go from lowest to highest priority order. Not very intuitive for sure.
Another trick is records?map(it -> {"k": it.Group + "\x00" + it.Item, "v": it})?sort_by("k")?map(it -> it.v). But it's slower, but can handle some trickier situations, where you have some key normalization or such.
The best solution would be to add sorting by a list of lambda expressions, but as of 2.3.34 that's not implemented. (PR-s are welcome.)
